# Relationship between ContentVersion object and Document object

Tags: document, contentversion

I currently have the ContentVersion information of a file I'm uploading, is there any way to find the Document Id using this info? Maybe through ContentDocumentLink or ContentDocument?

I wish to attain the Document ID to update the keywords field which is only associated with the Document object.

Edit:

```
for (ContentDocumentLink cd: Trigger.new) {
    if (cd.ContentDocumentId != null) {
        cont.ContentDocumentId = cd.ContentDocumentId;
    }
    System.debug('contentdocid = ' + cd.ContentDocumentId);
    cont1 = [SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId =: cd.ContentDocumentId limit 1];
}
```

ContentDocumentId is different to the DocumentId in the Document object as this error led me to believe.

```
13:02:59:039 FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

System.debug('contentdocid = ' + cd.ContentDocumentId);
```

This outputs

```
13:12:04:017 USER_DEBUG [24]|DEBUG|contentdocid = 06941000000vgsFAAQ
```

Which does not match with anything in the Document Object.

```
select Id from document where id = '06941000000vgsFAAQ'
```

0 rows.

Am I missing something?

Comment: As we can see from [Content Objects data model](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_content.htm#sforce_api_erd_content), `ContentDocumentId` is a field on `ContentVersion` object

Comment: Edited, to give you more information.

Comment: `select Id from contentDocument where id = '06941000000vgsFAAQ'` is what you need - `ContentDocument` is correct object name

Comment: Thanks so much! As the Document keywords are what I'm trying to access, is there a definitive relationship between ContentDocument and Document? I know I could search by name, but to be sure I'm selecting the right file.

Comment: You are confusing 2 different things  - Files (ContentDocument) and Document are not related at all.

Comment: But when I upload a file, Document contains things related to that file. I.E. keywords, does that not imply a relationship no?

Comment: Read [Differences Between Files, Salesforce CRM Content, Salesforce Knowledge, Documents, and Attachments](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_differences.htm&type=0) to understand what is what, it looks like keywords are used with `Documents`, while you are uploading `ContentDocuments`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Content Document:** It Represents a document that has been uploaded to a library in Salesforce CRM Content or Salesforce Files. The maximum number of documents that can be published is 30,000,000. This object record you don’t have to create. It gets created when you create ContentVersion which is the child of ContentDocument.

**Content Version:** Represents a specific version of a document in Salesforce CRM Content or Salesforce Files. In other words, this object stores document information similar like Attachment.

Now have a look on the relationship between these two objects below-
[image]

Now **ContentDocumentLink:** This object will share the files with Users, Records, Groups etc. You can create multiple records to attach the same files under multiple records.

Some useful SOQL queries on **Content Version** and **Content Document**-

**1.Get Content Document Id by Content Version Id**

```
SELECT ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion where Id = '068......'
```

**2.Get Content Version Id by Content Document Id**

```
SELECT Id from ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId = '069......'
```

**3.Get Download Number of Document by Version**

```
SELECT Count(Id), ContentVersionId FROM ContentVersionHistory where field='contentVersionDownloaded' and ContentVersion.ContentDocumentId  = '069....'   group by ContentVersionId
```

**4.Get Total Download Number for a Document**

```
SELECT Count(Id) FROM ContentVersionHistory where field='contentVersionDownloaded' and ContentVersion.ContentDocumentId = '069....' group by ContentVersion.ContentDocumentId
```

That's all from my end. I got these from different resources. Thanks.

Comment: Very informative. Where did you find this diagram? I would like to learn more.

Comment: @Arthlete https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_content.htm