# Can you explain the data tree that's created when you insert a file?

Tags: files, contentdocument

Can someone point me to documentation of the data tree/ that gets created (or confirm) when you insert a file in Salesforce? In testing I found that a ContentDocument, ContentVersion and 2 ContentDocumentLink records get created, but I can't find documentation for that.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_content.htm

Comment: Thanks @DavidCheng i saw those but those links don't address `how many content document links get created when you upload a file` that's a big part of what i'm after

Answer (score 1):

[Relationship between ContentVersion object and Document object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160198/relationship-between-contentversion-object-and-document-object) goes over the general model

- ContentDocument
- ContentVersion
- ContentDocumentLink

Your focus is on the behavior on upload - there's essentially two scenarios when uploading a file through the standard UI.

1. Upload a file through the files tab.
2. Upload a file while in a record context (object, library, groups, etc).

[ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm)

> A file can be shared with other users, groups, records, and Salesforce
> CRM Content libraries

Anywhere you can add the files through its related list or have an `Upload File` button covers the second scenario (object records, groups, library).

1. If you just upload a file to salesforce (Files tab), there will be a single `ContentDocument` and `ContentVersion` record along with one `ContentDoucmentLink`. This will be related to the `ContentDocument` through `ContentDocumentId` and your `User` through `LinkedEntityId`.
2. If you upload a file while in the context of another object (files related list, library) there will again be a single `ContentDocument` and `ContentVersion` record, but it will have 2 `ContentDocumentLink` records created and associated with the `ContentDocument` and:

   - `User`
   - Salesforce object you were on

You can always visually see this when looking at the file details in the `Shared with` related list right after uploading a document.

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks Kris.